# Is there a short hand in Julia for this list comprehension

Tags: list, julia

```
addresses = [
    "5412 N CLARK",
    "5148 N CLARK", 
    "5800 E 58TH",
    "2122 N CLARK",
    "5645 N RAVENSWOOD",
    "1060 W ADDISON",
    "4801 N BROADWAY",
    "1039 W GRANVILLE",
]

counts = [0, 3, 10, 4, 1, 7, 6, 1]

more5 = [n > 5 for n in counts]
a = [addresses[i] for i in eachindex(more5) if true == more5[i]]
println(a)
```

For the line :

```
a = [addresses[i] for i in eachindex(more5) if true == more5[i]]
```

any short hand is possible in Julia, say with `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest solution is just:

```
julia> addresses[counts .> 5]
3-element Vector{String}:
 "5800 E 58TH"
 "1060 W ADDISON"
 "4801 N BROADWAY"
```

This calculation `more5 = [n > 5 for n in counts]` is really just the same as `more5 = counts .> 5`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`filter`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.filter) in combination with array slicing:

```
julia> a = addresses[filter(i -> counts[i] > 5, 1:length(counts))]
3-element Vector{String}:
 "5800 E 58TH"
 "1060 W ADDISON"
 "4801 N BROADWAY"
```

Comment: `a = addresses[filter(i -> counts[i] > 5, eachindex(counts))]` also works

Answer (score 1):

Since `more5` is a boolean array, you can use it directly as a [logical index](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Logical-indexing):

```
julia> a = addresses[more5]
3-element Vector{String}:
 "5800 E 58TH"
 "1060 W ADDISON"
 "4801 N BROADWAY"
```

If you don't need `more5` for some other purpose, you can also just avoid allocating that intermediate array by doing:

```
julia> [a for (a, c) in Iterators.zip(addresses, counts) if c > 5]
3-element Vector{String}:
 "5800 E 58TH"
 "1060 W ADDISON"
 "4801 N BROADWAY"
```